# sqlite3 python negative row count

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

In the Below piece of Python Code, the rows are updating properly but I'm getting the number of rows updated as '-1'. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
import sqlite3


db = sqlite3.connect('contacts.sqlite')
Update_cursor=db.cursor()

db.execute('UPDATE contacts SET phone = 4867512 WHERE name="ABC"')
print('\n\n{} rows Updated.'.format(Update_cursor.rowcount))

Update_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM contacts")
#for row in Update_cursor:
#   print(row)

Update_cursor.close()

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Output

```
-1 rows Updated.
```

Comment: Use the cursor object to execute the statement and see if that works.